# How can I get the list of the active users and their commits in the repository in the given time period via github API?

Tags: python, github, github-api

I need to get the logins of the active users (max 30) and the number of their commits in a given period of time in a particular branch of the repository using github API v3 (https://developer.github.com/v3/) and the standard python libraries. I studied general api documentation, and https://developer.github.com/v3/repos/ and https://developer.github.com/v3/search/ articles in particular, but I couldn't find how to do that. It's possible to find commits through
`GET /search/commits` (by specifying the repository via the repo parameter: `https://api.github.com/search/commits?q=repo:octocat/Spoon-Knife`), but there will be neither time period nor the repository branch specified.

As a result, I was able to get the logins and contributions, but only for the whole time:

```
https://api.github.com/repos/octocat/Spoon-Knife/contributors
```

Also, in order to make search commits work, it's neccesary to provide a custom media type in the `Accept` header: `application/vnd.github.cloak-preview`
I've reworked an example from the documentation of how the `urlib` library works, but it returns `HTTP error 422`:

```
import urllib.request

API_URL = "https://api.github.com/"

q = urllib.request.Request('API_URL' + "search/commits?q=repo:octocat/Spoon-Knife")  

https://api.github.com/search/commits?q=repo:fastlane/fastlane
q.add_header('application/vnd.github.cloak-preview', 'Accept')
print(q)
a = urllib.request.urlopen(q)
a = a.read()
print(a)
```

Comment: check this for help: https://developer.github.com/v3/repos/commits/

Comment: Thanks for your answer.
Using this api function i can get all the commits for the time period.  
But how can I get repository's branch?
I suggest that in order to count all the commits of all the users I'll have to make a lot of requests. (And I've thought it could be done easier)

Comment: for filter and count, you have the route `/search`: https://developer.github.com/v3/search/#search-commits

the param `author` matches commits authored by a user